# Error: "Request failed with status code 500" con laravel en axios.put()

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, laravel-5.6

I am learning to work with laravel in this case version 5.6, by implementing a code with axios to update a table on my web page, I get the following message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RJ6o.png) the code I'm having problems with is the next

```js
actualizarCategoria(){
               if (this.validarCategoria()){
                    return;
                }
                
                let me = this;

                axios.put('/categoria/actualizar',{
                    'nombre': this.nombre,
                    'descripcion': this.descripcion,
                    'id': this.categoria_id
                }).then(function (response) {
                    me.cerrarModal();
                    me.listarCategoria();
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }); 
            }
```

Comment: can you show your axios configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that error 500 = error form your server. So your request may be malformed or it is a bug in your API (laravel side). Check your PHP logs you should see an error and look at the network tab in chrome to see the response from the server